# What's an idiom or a phrase that can be used to explain something's versatility?

Tags: phrases, idioms, idiom-meaning

What's an idiom or a phrase that can be used to explain something's versatility ?

Answer (score 1):

> 'It's the Swiss Army Knife of' drones / jackets / biological catalysis
>   / vehicles / suitcases / retirement cash flow / chalets / robots for rescue missions / smoke screens ....'

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife):

> The Swiss Army knife is a pocketknife or multi-tool manufactured by
>   Victorinox AG (and up to 2005 also by Wenger SA). The term "Swiss Army
>   knife" was coined by American soldiers after World War II due to the
>   difficulty they had in pronouncing "Offiziersmesser", the German
>   name....
>
> A cultural icon of Switzerland, the design of the knife and its
>   versatility have both led to worldwide recognition.

As for the metaphorical usage, which obviously refers to the versatility of an article, process etc, a Google search for "the Swiss army knife of" gives a great diversity of examples, including those given above (over half a million hits in total). A very versatile expression.